# Methods to prevent GPS sproofing in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I am thinking of how to prevent GPS spoofing in HTML5 by simulator mock location.

These are some of my ideas:

1. take more than one sample. In real situation, the GPS location should be moving. There should be some differences in real situation.
2. use a key to encrypt the data, so that the spoofers cannot see what is sending to server. But, by looking at the alogthrm in the code, they may be able to look at what are sending to the servers.

I know it is not easy in real situation. But still, I would like to prevent some of the cases. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: When the user is holding the device in their hand, or carrying it in their backpack, there's probably nothing you'll ever be able to do to avoid spoofing 100%. False positives in your detection methods are going to make people upset.

Comment: Maybe you just mean that you want to filter out possibly wrong GPS info. That's probably a legitimate thing to do: disable some location-based services if you're not sure of the GPS info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is based on a fundamental misunderstanding of [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#introduction).  It explicitly states:

> "Common sources of location information include Global Positioning
>   System (GPS) and location inferred from network signals such as IP
>   address, RFID, WiFi and Bluetooth MAC addresses, and GSM/CDMA cell
>   IDs, as well as **user input**. No guarantee is given that the API
>   returns the device's actual location. "

In other words, you're futilely trying to prevent something the specification explicitly allows.

Technically, it is also not that hard to create arbitrary user input.  Some highways are very straight, so a straight path with a small random perpendicular error is plausibly someone riding in a car.

Comment: Good answer. Also, why shouldn't the GPS coords be spoof-able? Preventing spoofing like this is like preventing the view-source option when making a webpage - totally unnecessary, and in fact, restricts the user.

Answer (score 1):

As @Pointy said, it's a difficult one from a purely technical perspective, though I'd probably look at monitoring accounts for sudden 'teleports' from one location to another in impossibly short amounts of time. If one minute they're at college and 1 minute later they're in a starbucks across town (or much further away), then something is off.

A simple check would be to track the most recent 'realistic' location of each user, then only permit an update to their location if the distance-vector over time between the old location and the new location is within a certain range.

This assumes however that the reason to prevent spoofing is to stop people 'corrupting' their account and claiming something based on their location (like gaming foursquare or whatever).

Comment: I agree with the teleports, but note that in urban areas (tall buildings) GPS receivers - especially the really bad ones in lots of phones - report teleporting all the time. Clearly teleporting from continent to continent would be suspicious.

Comment: I'd probably base it on a square-law, in ten seconds someone can travel anywhere within perhaps a half mile, in a minute perhaps a few miles, 10 minutes 20 miles, an hour 250 miles, a day 5000 miles. This would catch most local teleports within an 'innaccurate data' range, but still allow for reasonable updates to reflect reality

Comment: I implemented something similiar to this a few years ago on an XDA1 with Windows Mobile (the original version) to account for inaccurate data returned by the crappy GPS sensor and prevent messy updates to the location of our staff members (it also helped trim down their location to about 10 feet by consolidating all the readings and generating an average, though at the time required them to physically remain still for 30 seconds :)).

Comment: @BobDavies I'm building web app and need to detect geo-spoofing. wouldn't the teleportation speed check only work if the user changes the gps-coordinates while in the app? what if the user spoofs their location prior to opening the app.  also would averaging geo-coordinates work for a moving in a car?